# Referencing Fonts in Custom Themes for Keycloak

Tags: html, css, fonts, themes, keycloak

I have a custom theme derived from the base theme and try to reference custom fonts in my stylesheets. For some reason, I cannot make it work. I haven’t found any documentation or example that involves fonts, so I did some trial and error.

File structure:

```
└── theme/
    └── my-theme/
        ├── login/
        │   ├── *.ftl
        │   ├── messages/
        │   │   └── *.properties
        │   └── theme.properties
        ├── common/
        │   └── resources/
        │       ├── css/
        │       │   └── my-style.css
        │       └── fonts/
        │           ├── font-name.woff
        │           ├── font-name.woff2
        │           └── font-name.ttf
        └── login
```

File theme.properties:

```
parent=base
import=common/my-theme
styles=css/my-style.css
```

File my-style.css:

```
[...]
@font-face {
    font-family: "font-name";
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    src: font-url("../fonts/font-name.woff2") format("woff2"),
    font-url("../fonts/font-name.woff") format("woff"),
    font-url("../fonts/font-name.ttf") format("truetype");
}
body {
    font-family: font-name !important;
}
[...]
```

What is the path I have to define in my-style.css? I tried all kind of variations and even copied the fonts directly into the css directory. All without any success.

Comment: Everything seems fine, did you try some google font with `www` type url to see that in general the text gets the applied font, may be font-family is `overriden` later in style.css with `!important`?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I just tried Roboto and Ephesis. After adding the corresponding font face blocks and changing the font family, the fonts were loaded and worked perfectly fine.

Comment: When checking the inspector in Firefox, I can see that the correct styling is used (font-family: font-name !important). But in the fonts tab, it shows the default system font - DejaVu Serif in my case. I think that confirms that the stylesheet is working but the fonts files cannot be found.

Comment: Ok, so its a server issue not a front end one. Try accessing the font file, like a downloadable resource, that is `www.yourwebsite/root/theme/my-theme/common/resources/fonts/font-name.woff` I think your server would have restricted access it. You should mention your server details and the back end language being used. Also check the networks tab in dev tools if the browser  is tying to access the fonts.

Comment: Keycloak comes with its own server that is based on WildFly Application Server and is mainly implemented in Java. For templates, they use Freemarker templates and some sort of asset management. That's why the path to the font files is not directly obvious. I assume the asset management does not find my files with the given path when processing the theme template and therefore cannot make it available. But I am not sure. I also haven't found anything in the logs so far.

Comment: After some digging, I found out that the font files are accessible under /auth/resources/[cryptic string]/common/my-theme/fonts/font-name.[woff2, woff, ttf]. When I use this path in the stylesheet, it is actually working. The problem here is the cryptic string that is probably generated by the asset management and might change anytime. So it would be much better to use a more generic path in the stylesheet.

Comment: @wojja, Could you please explain how did you solve it?

Comment: @amirtbi I put the font files in theme/my-theme/common/resources/fonts and then used src: url("../fonts/font-name.woff2") and similar for the other formats in my-style.css under theme/my-theme/common/resources/css.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution was actually to replace `font-url` by `url` in the stylesheet as `font-url` is no valid CSS:

```css
/*...*/
@font-face {
    font-family: "font-name";
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    src: url("../fonts/font-name.woff2") format("woff2"),
    url("../fonts/font-name.woff") format("woff"),
    url("../fonts/font-name.ttf") format("truetype");
}
body {
    font-family: font-name !important;
}
/*...*/
```